# Exercism: determine if a word or phrase is an isogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, programming-challenge, strings

**The task:**

> Determine if a word or phrase is an isogram.
> An isogram (also known as a "nonpattern word") is a word or phrase without a repeating letter, however spaces and hyphens are allowed to appear multiple times.

**Examples of isograms:**

- lumberjacks
- background
- downstream
- six-year-old

*The word isograms, however, is not an isogram, because the s repeats.*

Even though I'm aware that questions about isograms have already been posted, in this variation of the problem spaces and hyphens are allowed to appear multiple times so that you can not use a solution such as `len(string) == len(set(string))`

What bothers me about my solution is hardcoding bounds of `ascii` character ranges and using `collections` library for such a small problem. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
from collections import Counter

ASCII_LOWER_BOUND = 97
ASCII_UPPER_BOUND = 123

def is_isogram(string):
    char_counts = Counter(string.lower())
    return all(
        char_counts[char] == 1 
        for char in char_counts 
        if ord(char) in range(ASCII_LOWER_BOUND, ASCII_UPPER_BOUND + 1)
        )
```

And a test suite provided by exercism:

````
import unittest

from isogram import is_isogram

# Tests adapted from `problem-specifications//canonical-data.json` @ v1.7.0


class IsogramTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_empty_string(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram(""), True)

    def test_isogram_with_only_lower_case_characters(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("isogram"), True)

    def test_word_with_one_duplicated_character(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("eleven"), False)

    def test_word_with_one_duplicated_character_from_the_end_of_the_alphabet(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("zzyzx"), False)

    def test_longest_reported_english_isogram(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("subdermatoglyphic"), True)

    def test_word_with_duplicated_character_in_mixed_case(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("Alphabet"), False)

    def test_word_with_duplicated_character_in_mixed_case_lowercase_first(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("alphAbet"), False)

    def test_hypothetical_isogrammic_word_with_hyphen(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("thumbscrew-japingly"), True)

    def test_hypothetical_word_with_duplicated_character_following_hyphen(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("thumbscrew-jappingly"), False)

    def test_isogram_with_duplicated_hyphen(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("six-year-old"), True)

    def test_made_up_name_that_is_an_isogram(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("Emily Jung Schwartzkopf"), True)

    def test_duplicated_character_in_the_middle(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("accentor"), False)

    def test_same_first_and_last_characters(self):
        self.assertIs(is_isogram("angola"), False)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## ord()

Do not define constants like `ASCII_LOWER_BOUND`, use `ord('a')`. Easy to read, no uncertainty about the value.

## character range/set

Do not use an integer range and ord(). It is error prone and hard to review.

```
if ord(char) in range(ASCII_LOWER_BOUND, ASCII_UPPER_BOUND + 1)
```

rewrites to

```
import string
if char in string.ascii_lowercase
```

No off by one, easy to read. If the test has to be very fast prepare a set.

## generator expression

`Counter` is derived from `dict`. So instead of

```
(char_counts[char] == 1 for char in char_counts if char in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

we do use `dict().items()`

```
(count == 1 for char, count in char_counts.items() if char in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

## Naming

In general you should try to avoid names that hide common python names. As we want to import string we need a different name for the parameter.

```
from collections import Counter
import string

def is_isogram(word):
    char_counts = Counter(word.lower())
    return all(count == 1 for char, count in char_counts.items() if char in string.ascii_lowercase)
```

Comment: Actually ```string``` paramater name is used by Exercism. Don't understand why you loop through ```char_counts.items()``` instead of original ```char_counts```.

Comment: looping - By iterating over `char_counts` I get the keys only. By iterating over `char_counts.items()` I get key/value pairs. I can use `count` directly without having to dereference `char_counts[char]`. This is more efficient.

Comment: a `set` is better for a containment check than a `str`, so I would do `lower_cases = set(string.ascii_lowercase)` and then later `if char in lower_cases`

Comment: @Maarten. My words above :-)

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate once over text and short-circuit right away if any character is not unique.

```
import string


def is_isogram(text):
    seen = set()
    for char in text:
        if (lower := char.lower()) in string.ascii_lowercase:
            if lower in seen:
                return False
            else: 
                seen.add(lower)
    return True
```

Comment: What does ```:=``` mean in Python?

Comment: This is [assignment expression](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) also known as 'walrus operator' available starting from Python 3.8